# Sorry, we can't open 'http://xxx/xx.xlsx' because the server isn't responding. When opening an excel (or word) in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library

I recently found an issue in SharePoint 2013, where I am not able to Office documents from SharePoint Library, **Which was working fine last week!!!.**

When I click on the file, it says

```
Sorry, we can't open 'http://xxx/xx.xlsx' because the server isn't responding.
```

[image]

[image]

It was working fine last week and no changes are made after that. This is a very critical feature for my client and I need to resolve it quickly. I have SharePoint 2013 Standard and Microsoft Office Professional plus.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I often resolve a lot of issues simply by repairing the office setup. Not sure if that could be the case but it wouldn't hurt. Otherwise, you can have an issue at the server side, so check ULS logs, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys this problem is solved. Its not an issue from SharePoint; neither from Microsoft office.

The IT team has installed and setup some new firewall, which was blocking the traffic from SharePoint site.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps once

1. Close all Office applications.
   Make sure SharePoint Worksapce was not  running in the system tray
2. Clear all the files located under

"c:\Users\login_user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\14.0\OfficeFileCache"

Comment: Tried it, still same issue :(

Comment: If multiple users/devs are using the same machine. You might have to clear other users cache as well. If that too doesn't work try running SysMon from Sysinternals to see for any file lock

Comment: Only one user id using this machine and i am facing this same issue in another client employees machine as well.

Comment: Have you installed any  office updates  or SharePoint  new KB files (Patches,CM updates) recently..?

Comment: Windows auto update is ON, on all the machines, i checked the update history on control panel and there many updates installed on last Monday for Microsoft office.