# Sorry, we cannot open the ' url ' because the server isnt responding.

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I am getting this error while opening a document.

[image: Error image]

How to resolve the error?

Comment: Is it only you or other users are also facing this error?

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons behind this error

1. Check if you can view site pages etc.
2. If possible try clearing office cache
3. Try open another file
4. Check if its a permission issue
5. Check the server is running fine and have enough disk-space/memory/cpu
6. Worst case - try restarting IIS application pool
7. Check your office version

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Add the SharePoint site into trusted sites and check the result.
2. Repair the office application. Go to control panel->uninstall a program->right click Microsoft office 2010->change->repair.
3. Check if there is some firewall policy blocking the traffic from SharePoint site. There is a similar post below:

[Sorry, we can't open 'http://xxx/xx.xlsx' because the server isn't responding. When opening an excel (or word) in SharePoint 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/213258/sorry-we-cant-open-http-xxx-xx-xlsx-because-the-server-isnt-responding-w)